# How do I set a default value using enum type in column Mysql using Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, enums, database-migration, knex.js, adonis.js

I am using AdonisJS to make a backend application. In migrations, specifically in models, we have the option of creating models, but I can't use a default value in enun type. After reading the Knex.js documentation, I couldn't find a way to put this default value in enum type (table.enu) in SGDB Mysql. Could anyone help?

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/migrations

http://knexjs.org/#Schema-enum

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try `defaultTo()` :

**defaultTo — column.defaultTo(value)**

**Sets the default value for the column on an insert.**

*[From knex Documentation](http://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#defaultto)*

Example :

```js
table.enu('role', ['one', 'two', 'three']).defaultTo('two', options={})
```

*[Adonis Enu/Enum documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/table-builder#enum--enu)*

*[Adonis defaultTo documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/table-builder#defaultto)*